# Does Notational Velocity/nvALT securely sync with Simplenote?

Tags: macos, mac, sync, notational-velocity

I set nvALT to use a single database to store and sync my notes. Using a database has the benefit of having encryption.

I just noticed this warning at the bottom of the synchronization settings window that says "Note contents will be delivered in clear text." This came as a bit of a shock because I do have some personal sensitive information stored in nvALT.

I searched for the syncing APIs of Simplenote which seem to use HTTPS but I'm not sure about that. Can anyone explain how the synchronization works exactly and what the warning message means?

Comment: I almost want to use Wireshark to see what's going on underneath.

Comment: I second that it would be far more direct than looking at the code for nvalt at https://github.com/ttscoff/nv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is hard-coded [here](https://github.com/ttscoff/nv/blob/master/SimplenoteSession.m#L62) to provide the different API URLs. It's the only location in the sources where `simple-note.appspot.com` is used.

---

All uses of that method outside the same file are in these files:

- [SimplenoteEntryCollector.m](https://github.com/ttscoff/nv/blob/master/SimplenoteEntryCollector.m)
- [NotationPrefsViewController.m](https://github.com/ttscoff/nv/blob/master/NotationPrefsViewController.m) (for verifying login information)

In neither of them, the basic URL (domain, scheme) is changed.

---

*But* the notes themselves are not encrypted. So, while the *transport* uses SSL, Simplenote will receive and store your notes however they do, and anyone with access to your Simplenote account can access them.